# How to render set of Form API elements?

Tags: theming, forms

I have an array like the following.

```
$form["something"]["something"] = array(
  0 => array( "#markup" => "line 0" ),
  1 => array( "#markup" => "line 1" ),
  2 => array( "#markup" => "line 2" ),
);
```

When rendering it in the theme function with `drupal_render($form["something"]["something"])`, I get only the first line.

> line 0

When I try to use `foreach`, this somehow does not return anything.

So what am I doing wrong? Should I modify an array itself and add some wrapper element? I would prefer to render it all with one line, without `foreach`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `drupal_render()`, you should use [drupal_render_children()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render_children/7).

```
print drupal_render_children($form["something"]["something"]);
```